# How do I get Heroku to work on Ubuntu 10.10 (using VirtualBox on Windows machine)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm a newbie following the RailsTutorial.org program and have installed/setup rvm, ruby 1.9.2,rails, curl, git and created my first app and pushed it to github (so the SSH key is fine).

The next step is deploying to Heroku, which is killing me:

```
gem install Heroku
```

works fine but I get this error after "heroku keys:add" or "heroku create":

```
    [app_first (master)]$ heroku keys:add
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)
 from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
 from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.11.0/lib/heroku/commands/app.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
 from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
 from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
 from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.11.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
 from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.11.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:5:in `each'
 from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.11.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
 from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
 from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
 from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.11.0/bin/heroku:7:in `<top (required)>'
 from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
 from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>
```

My guess is it's something to do with missing or misplaced gems, but I'm a total rookie so the guess may be way off.  here's the gem environment:

```
[app_first (master)]$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial
     - /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Any ideas? Grateful in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it!  Or rather, a buddy got it for me.  Here's a [link to the solution](http://dirk.net/2009/04/05/no-such-file-to-load-readline-loaderror-when-running-scriptconsole/).

Answer (score 4):

Hey.. I completed the Installation process with rvm, ruby 1.9.2 and sqlite3. You gave up in the last step :) :)

Alright my solution.. this worked for me after 2 days of wrestling with heroku :)

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev

cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p249/ext/readline
```

and then build the extension

```
ruby extconf.rb && make  && make install
```

Answer (score 4):

```
gem install rb-readline
```

solved it for me.

source:  https://gist.github.com/1080765

Comment: thanks! This solved that same problem (see original question) I have. I am on Windows + Cygwin + gVIM

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Prozac!
I have done a multi-user install of RVM on Ubuntu 11.10
The following worked for me, using ruby 1.9.2:

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev

cd /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ext/readline/

ruby extconf.rb && make && make install
```

Answer (score 0):

The herkou documentation is awesome. These are the instructions that you want on the [heroku docs](http://docs.heroku.com/keys)

Comment: I went to their docs already - no luck.  The SSH Keys doc is the same as github and, since I can successfully push to github, I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: ooops...hit enter too soon.  after the doc on keys they go right to "heroku create" and "heroku keys:add" which is where my environment craps out.  Couldn't find any related troubleshooting for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

upgrading from ruby-1.9.2-p180 to ruby-1.9.2-p290 did it for me